# Why two linux systems has different memory usage for same processes?

Tags: memory

I have a desktop and a laptop running Arch Linux. Both have Intel i3 process, desktop with i3 3rd gen, while the laptop runs i3 6th gen. Both have 4 GB RAM + 4 GiB ZRAM.

But I have seen that the desktop is much much faster. It's true that desktop processors faster, but my concern is a bit different. While both laptop and desktop have identical processes, same kernel parameters, same versions of compiler, the desktop uses around 200 MB lesser RAM the laptop. Take a look at the gnome-system-monitor:

**gnome-system-monitor on Laptop**
[image: gnome-system-monitor on desktop]

**gnome-system-monitor on Desktop**
[image]

By comparing xfdesktop to xfdesktop, whiskermenu to whiskermenu, nm-applet to nm-applet, and so on, I have noticed that the similar processes use more memory on the laptop than the desktop. My first thought was that because the desktop runs 1366x768 res display, while the laptop runs 1920x1080 HDMI (laptop screen is set to off and HDMI is on). So I changed the res of my laptop to even smaller than the desktop, rebooted, and saw the reported memory usages is identical to the previous one.

As reported by gnome-system-monitor, the desktop boots at 670 MiB but the laptop boots at 880 MiB. Enabled systemd services are also identical for both the systems.

I also launched a ruby interpreter to see if the desktop uses more memory than the laptop, and I found out both laptop and desktop consuming the same amount of memory with the same program.

The only thing that differs for both the systems are the kernel compiled with `-march=native -mtune=native` option.

#### Here's the output from `cat /proc/version`

**Laptop**

```
Linux version 5.8.5-xanmod1-1-xanmod (makepkg@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 02 Sep 2020 20:22:18 +0000
```

**Desktop**

```
Linux version 5.8.5-xanmod1-1-xanmod (makepkg@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 02 Sep 2020 17:49:52 +0000
```

The kernels had the same config file during compilation. And I don't think that much memory difference is solely for the kernel, because both the systems are 64 bit, and also, I have previously used the `linux`, and `linux-zen` packages from Arch repo - even with the same kernel, I saw that difference.

---

What's causing such difference in memory for the processes on the laptop and desktop?

**EDIT 1: Possible Solution:**

I have no idea why but on my laptop, I first changed the theme (Appearance theme from XFCE4 settings). Then I switched back to the one I was using. I rebooted (probably logout will also work), and now the memory usage is reduced even though I am using the same theme.

**EDIT 2: Possible Solution:**

Nope, I was wrong in the Edit 1.
I did one more step before changing the theme.

I use the Papirus icon theme.

I had two copies of Papirus icon theme, latest version in `/home/sourav/.icons/` directory and a very old one in  `/usr/share/icons`.

If I remove Papirus from `/usr/share/icons`, the memory usage is 700 MiB after reboot. If I again copy the `/home/sourav/.icons/Papirus` to `/usr/share/icons` and then reboot, the memory usage is 960 MiB. For both cases, I had a cache generated with `gtk-update-icon-cache`.

I previously had no idea that similar copy of an icon theme in different places could account for 150 MB more memory usage!

Here's the screenshot of gnome-system-monitor on laptop after deleting one copy of the same icon from /usr/share/icons:

[image]

It's using way less memory than the previous screenshot.

Comment: The laptop has several processes running that the desktop doesn't have. The are many other factors that determine overall speed and efficiency such as the system bus. It's also highly unlikely that the two have the exact same RAM and motherboard.

Comment: True, but overall compare the xfce4 related processes - like xfwm4, whiskermenu, network-manager-applet (sits on xfce4-panel on notification addon). After deleting the icons from /usr/share/icons, the problem is absolutely gone, that was the problem in the first place. The lesson I learnt is that never ever keep two icon theme in two different folders with XFCE4 (14.4).

Comment: Why was it a problem? Why do you think that two different machines should run in the exact same way? Deleting icons doesn't have any effect on the efficiency of a computer whether it's a desktop or a laptop.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. The problem was xfce4 on my laptop was using a lot more memory than it should. Let's talk solely about the laptop. Turned out the identical icon themes in two different places were the root of the issue. If you I delete the icon theme from /usr/share/icons, 200 MB memory gets available after boot on the laptop. The desktop had only one copy, so the memory usage were lower. Now the laptop and desktop has identical memory usage.

Comment: To reproduce, download an icon theme, decompress it, copy the theme first into ~/.icons. Then change the theme from settings. Then reboot (probably logout will also work). Take a note of the memory footprint. Now make a copy of the ~/.icons to /usr/share/icons, and reboot. The memory usage is now 150 MiB more (right after the boot) than the previous boot.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand anything. You said that the laptop was running more slowly than the desktop. A single process using 200MB of memory isn't going to make a machine any less efficient. If you are that worried about a process using 200MB of memory, then you need to add more to the system. From what the specs are, the real issue is that you are running two computers in 2020 with only 4GB of memory. Ubuntu and Windows would eat them both alive. So would anything more than Solitaire and Minesweeper. Several Firefox tabs with Youtube and Facebook would take them down.

Comment: Sorry, 200 MB memory usage isn't a big deal. But if you keep two copies of your current icon theme in two different places, it hogs 200 MB more memory (for nothing). So if you delete one copy, you make 200 MB available, and the look and feel doesn't change. I think that's a bug. 4 GB RAM isn't an issue for me, with ZRAM, I run Firefox, Ruby on Rails, Redis server, visual studio code, and still left with > 1 GB available memory. That's not the issue. The issue is probably XFCE bug I think. And I have solved my issue (read the Edit 2 section in the question)...

Comment: If 4GB of RAM is enough, then why did you feel the need to post a question about something using 200 measly MB of it? My Windows XP and Fedora machines in 2008-2009 had 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Read the question again. Come back. 200 memory isn't a lot (not a lot to you, but I love micro-optimization for my programs, and I am concerned even with 1 KB more memory usage). Here you are wasting 200 memory for nothing, and delete one copy of icon, and solve the issue. Again and again I am telling you the same story. Sorry, but this is my last comment to you. I am happy to delete the question, but kept it because it might help others. If you don't understand the question please don't spam with such comments that makes no sense.

Comment: I don't need to read the question again. Why don't you make up your mind? Either the 4GB is enough or it's not. If it were, then you wouldn't be so worried about 200MB of it being used but you are so that would indicate that would indicate that it's not sufficient. I am addressing your question so it isn't spam. If you don't want to hear what I have to say, then perhaps you shouldn't post questions here.